# ORDER BY column_name help (via link in HTML table view) (PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

My output for my table in HTML has several columns such as userid, name, age, dob.

The table heading is simply the title of the column name, I want this to be a link, and when clicked, the selected column is sorted in order, ASC, and then DESC (on next click). I thought this was pretty straight forward but I'm having some difficulty.

So far, I have produced this, and no output is taken, apart from the URL works by displaying 'users.php?orderby=userid'

```
<?php
          if(isset($_GET['orderby'])){ 
$orderby = $_GET['orderby']; 
$query_sv = "SELECT * FROM users BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($orderby)." ASC"; 
} 
//default query 
else{ 
$query_sv = "SELECT * FROM users BY user_id DESC"; 
} 
?>


              <tr>
                <th><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_SELF']."?orderby=userid";?>">User ID</a></th>
```

Hoefully if I get this working, I can sort the users by D.O.B. next also using the same principles. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$orders=array("name","price","qty");
$key=array_search($_GET['orderby'],$orders));
$orderby=$orders[$key];
$query="SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY $orderby";
```

Comment: What exactly would I put within my <th> tags then as the link? Is it stil necessary to use the $_SERVER global

Comment: @Derek No, You don't need to use $_SERVER, especially if you fail to write in proper case. `<a href="?orderby=userid">`

Comment: this worked an absolute treat! Thanks a lot. However, is there a way that when I click the column title again, the order is reserved? At the moment it sorts it in descending (i.e. 1, 5, 12) If I click again, I want it to be 12, 5, 1? Is this a simple solution?

Answer (score 1):

It should be `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY ...` instead of `SELECT * FROM users BY ...`. Also you might want to check that the passed parameter is a valid column name, otherwise your query will fail.

Comment: Yea I just saw that issue, however I changed it and still no luck, nothing happens :(

Answer (score 1):

To add a direction would be more complicated.

First you need to make a conditional parameter.

```
if (empty($_GET['asc'])) {
  $orderby.=" DESC"; 
  $dir="&asc=1";
} else {
  $orderby.=" ASC"; 
  $dir="";
}
```

Now put $orderby into query and $dir into link:

```
<a href="?orderby=userid<?php echo $dir?>">
```